# Summarize and merging a list and its counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of data combined that is placed side by side.  How do I summarize and map their values:

**My List:**

```
country = ['Australia', 'Australia', 'UAE', 'Australia', 'Israel', 'Ghana', 'Ghana']
views = [1, 2, 4, 5, 77, 5, 2]
```

While I've been able to map them side by side...like this:

```
"Australia: 1",
"Australia: 2",
"UAE: 4",
"Australia: 5",
"Israel: 77",
"Ghana: 5",
"Ghana: "2"
```

**What I tried:**

```
result = dict(zip(country, views))
{'Australia': 5, 'UAE': 4, 'Israel': 77, 'Ghana': 2}
```

**I would like to get their summary and summation on both sides...like this:**

```
"data": {
    "countries": [
        "Australia: 8",
        "UAE: 4",
        "Israel: 77",
        "Ghana: 7"]}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. A dictionary with a list of strings

Comment: dictionary has Unique keys I guess,That is not unexpected to say the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict(int)` to increment the counts:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> country = ['Australia', 'Australia', 'UAE', 'Australia', 'Israel', 'Ghana', 'Ghana']
>>> views = [1, 2, 4, 5, 77, 5, 2]

>>> summary = defaultdict(int)
>>> for c, v in zip(country, views):
...     summary[c] += v
... 
>>> summary
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Australia': 8, 'UAE': 4, 'Israel': 77, 'Ghana': 7})
```

Using `defaultdict(int)` implicitly sets the initial count to 0.  Here's an explanation from the `collections` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory):

> Setting the default_factory to int makes the defaultdict useful for counting (like a bag or multiset in other languages).
>
> When a letter is first encountered, it is missing from the mapping, so the default_factory function calls `int()` to supply a default count of zero. The increment operation then builds up the count for each letter.

To get to your "intended output" exactly:

```
d = {}; d['data'] = {'countries': dict(summary)}
```

Comment: Or `collections.Counter`